Upgrade 23.04 to 24.04.1
I want to upgrade from 23.04 to 24.04.1. What upgrade loader should I install and how to I download it please? I understand I should avoid 24.04. The only answers I have found do not upgrade to 24.04.1.

Ubuntu 23.04 has reached the end of its life (EOL) on January 25, 2024. Ubuntu does not allow skipping versions while upgrading. That means you could only upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10. The version 23.10 has reached the EOL in July 11, 2024. That means there is no easy upgrade path from 23.04.

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is the release, Ubuntu 24.04.1 is newer install media (a fresh ISO) which as announcements say is "this point release includes many updates and updated installation media has been provided so that fewer updates will need to be downloaded after installation" only you're not asking about a new install are you?  but an upgrade to 24.04 only (24.04.1 is new media; which will install an updated 24.04 system).

The nobleupgrades doc outlining supported upgrades is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades but you'll note only mention of 22.04 & 23.10 are included. The only upgrade intended for 23.04 was to 23.10 (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades) but that's far more complex now given 23.10 is EOL.

So, I understand from all of this that Ubuntu will not let me upgrade from 23.04. At all. Disappointed in Ubuntu.

Refer to EOLUpgrades on how to do it... and be aware it's a much more manual task due to your missing the window. The easy (one command) applied for six months after EOL, but you missed that window thus the more laborious task of upgrade. I non-destructively re-install Lubuntu noble over my lunar so I'd lost no data files & my manually installed apps re-installed automatically.. so you may have options; but release-upgrade from 23.04 was to 23.10 as its in the same two year development cycle (22.10, 23.04, 23.10 & 24.04 being same cycle; thru all OR prior 22.04 to 24.04)
